# Ladakh medical facilities

Tags: india, health, transportation

I'm planning to visit Ladakh in July with an 11-year-old kid. I am flying to Leh from Delhi. Has anyone here travelled with a kid this route before? Were there any issues due to altitude  sickness? I will be in Leh for two days to acclimatise. Any hospitals anyone can recommend in case of altitude sickness?

Answer (score 1):

Ladakh is a beautiful place but yes there are altitude issues during the month of  August TO December, there are fluctuations in degree of temperatures, As you're flying by air there wouldn't be a travel hassle.
And as soon as you land the Airport Authorities help in medication for Altitude sickness.
You should visit the nearby hospital for reference and generally there are Military Hospital camps for every 5 Kms.

2 days won't be hassle for the kid if he isn't affected by any breathing issues, if travelling  this July then temperature falls upto -30c so it is better you prepare yourself to stay warm with good clothing.

Pro tip: Visit a doctor in Delhi and you can take precautionary advice before you fly.

Answer (score 1):

When I visited Leh, I did not find hospitals as often as we would in other towns. It is advisable to carry (at the very least) Diamox because it helps in risky situations - so that you get the time to go and reach out for advice.  I have seen people carry oxygen backup (like oxy99) - but I dont have first hand experience.  For me, 2 days of rest was optimum, not the planned one day for acclimatization.

For local wisdom, just in case you might need, do visit the Leh market there and ask people (most people will only help minus any business vested interests).  In market, most local people come, hence we can get accurate local information.  Also, there are army camps near the airport area - and you will find army women / men - who can give you solid advice.